# How to improve slow mobile speed rating when using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, mobile

Im using [testmysite](https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com/) from google and cant get above %67 mobile speed when using angular. The site is just a html menu bar, two lines of text and angular js. I have angular js and angular routes linked via CDN and my script.js minified.like this w/defer tag

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" defer></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js" defer></script>
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

which I would think is the fastest way (I doubt the test factors in caching)

Ive also tried combining all three into one minified file and including the async tag ala

```
<script src="script.js" async></script>
```

but still around the same speed maybe even slower

Can someone let me know how I can improve the speed?

Comment: Check this, can be useful https://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/

Comment: What speed is the tool complaining about exactly? Did you check out the "see what to fix" section that offers details on what went wrong?

Comment: "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"